# Included view overwriting sections of parent view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a view `parent.view` that includes another view `child.view`. `parent.view` extends `parent.layout` and `child.view` extends `child.layout`. They both have a section `content`. When including the child view, the `parent.view`'s `content` is overwritten by the `child.view`'s `content`. This doesn't seem like the correct behavior. Is there any way around this?

Parent View:

```
@extends('parent.layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>Foo</h1>

    @include('child.view')
@show
```

Child View:

```
@extends('child.layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>Bar</h1>
@stop
```

Expected Result:

```
<h1>Foo</h1>
<h1>Bar</h1>
```

Actual Result:

```
<h1>Bar</h1>
```

Comment: Did you try using `@parent` in your `Child View`?

Comment: @TimLewis Unfortunately the include is nested in the parent's markup, so calling `@parent` simply puts it at the beginning or the end of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try name spacing the `@section`'s.

In parent view:

```
@section('parent.content')
```

In parent layout:

```
@yield('parent.content')
```

Etc.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, although it feels hacky.